# Application Insightsでカスタムカウンターがリストに出てこない

Tags: azure

ApplicationInsights.configにカスタムカウンターを追加したのですが
Application Insightsでカスタムカウンターがリストに出てきません。

Comment: @kazutoさん、せっかくご自分で詳細な回答を投稿されているので、多くの人にこの回答を読んでいただくためにも、質問の状況をもう少し詳細にシェアされてみてはいかででしょうか。そうすることで、kazutoさんの問題がより具体的に理解されるようになり、この質問の価値もあがると思います。タイトルと質問文は再編集可能です。

Comment: 遅くなりましたが、ご提案ありがとうございます。
状況を説明しやすいテストコードを書いてみようと思います。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

Application Insightsはとても便利なのですが、色々と気難しい部分があります。特にCustom Counterは中々にすんなり出てくれない問題があり地味に苦労するケースが多いです。

その様なときは以下の対応などに注意してみてください。

**・そもそもカスタムカウンターが登録出来ない**

WebRoleから登録しようとすると色々と深みにハマります。ただしググると色々出てきます。

Custom Performance Counters in Windows Azure

http://blog.elastacloud.com/2011/01/14/implementing-custom-performance-counters-in-windows-azure-sdk-1-3/

Windows Azure Diagnosticsのパフォーマンス カウンターをプラグイン化して使う

http://blogs.gine.jp/taka/archives/2128

とりあえず私は前者のページを参考にwebrole実行前にcustom counterを登録するだけのexeを用意して対応しました。

**・Base カウンターをApplicationInsights.configに記載しない**

良く考えるとそりゃそうだなんですがマルチカウンターのベース値の方はApplicationInsights.configに設定してはいけません。していると、何の警告も無く、そのカウンターが出ません。この何も出ないのが辛いよね・・

**・ApplicationInsights.configにカウンターを重複させない**

これも地味にひっかかる人が居るケース。特にWebRoleを作ってると、ちまちまとdiagnostics.wadcfgやApplicationInsights.configに何度も編集したりしているとミスしやすいです。一度形が出来ると自動化出来るので、ミスが減るのですが形が出来るまでにハマるパタンで案の定ハマりました